# Error: Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I found this error:

```
Error: Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, 
ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I am encountering this error, in my selenium test automation with mocha js, below are my two codes and the `package.json`. I really am not able to resolve. Can someone help me please?

```js
    it('Steps para criação de GR', async function () {
                this.timeout(26000);
                await grpage.clickFinancial();
    
                await grpage.ButtonGr();
    
                await grpage.NewGr();
            });
```